# remi リポジトリから PHP7.3 をインストールした際、php.ini が見つからない

Tags: php, rhel

AWSのRed Hat Enterprise LinuxにPHPの環境構築を行っていますが、php.ini が見つからない状態です。

[RHEL 8・CentOS 8 に PHP 7.3 をインストールする (remi 使用)](https://xn--o9j8h1c9hb5756dt0ua226amc1a.com/?p=4022)

上記のページを参考にremiのPHP7.3をインストールをしました。
`php -v` でphpのバージョン情報は確認できます。
`/etc/` にあることが多いようですが、php.ini が存在しません。

何が原因なのでしょうか。インストールがうまくいっていないのでしょうか。

原因や対処法がありましたらご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remi リポジトリからインストールするパッケージについては、OS標準で提供しているパッケージとの競合を避けるために別ディレクトリにインストールされる場合があります。

[Replacement of the base packages ? | FAQ - Remi's RPM repository](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#policy)

バージョンは多少違いますが、例えば以下で紹介されているコマンドをベースに rpm コマンドでパッケージに含まれるファイルの一覧を手掛かりに調べる方法があります。

[remi の php70 パッケージについて調べてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hotta/items/3fbf4debf13bbe87fb53)

```
$ rpm -ql php73-php-common | grep php.ini
```

もしくはより汎用的な方法として、`locate` コマンドでファイルを検索する方法もあります。

```
$ locate php.ini
```

Comment: `rpm -ql php73-php-common | grep php.ini`を実行したら`/etc/opt/remi/php73/php.ini`にあることが分かりました。ありがとうございます。