# /var/log/php/error.log へのログ出力を無効にしたい

Tags: php, centos

ログファイルを出力しないよう設定しているつもりなのに、`/var/log/php/error.log`にデータが(一晩で10GB 以上)追記されていきます。理由としては何が考えられますか？

#### 試したこと

・/etc/php.ini の内容が

> log_errors = Off

となっていることを確認

・`$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm` を実行
・`$ sudo systemctl restart nginx` を実行
・「php-fpm」については「/var/log/php-fpm/」にフォルダがあるので、この件とは関係がないと思われます。
・`$ less /etc/php-fpm.conf`を実行したら

> error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log

となっていました。

他に考えられることは、PHPファイルに `/var/log/php/error.log` へログ出力するよう直接指定している可能性ぐらいですか？

##### 環境

CentOS 7
PHP 8.2

---

2/11 追記
「lsof コマンド」を打ったら、「11:58:17 nginx 2889 root 3w REG 253,4 8998912 25173685 /var/log/php/error.log」となったので、

```
# ps -fp 2889
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2889     1  0  2月09 ?      00:00:02 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

しかし、「$ less /etc/nginx/nginx.conf」を打っても「error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;」とあるだけで、「/var/log/php/error.log」はどこにも記載がありませんでした。

Comment: 実際にログに記録されている内容から推測できませんか？もしくは `lsof` コマンドでファイルを開いているプロセスを確認する…辺りかと。

Comment: 過去の質問では remi-php を利用しているような話も出ていたので、その場合は `/etc/php.ini` ではなく別の場所かもしれません。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67068/3060

Comment: 「lsof コマンド」を打ったら、「11:58:17 nginx      2889                 root    3w      REG              253,4    8998912   25173685 /var/log/php/error.log」となりましたが、「ファイルを開いているプロセスを確認する」とは具体的にここからどうすればよいですか？

Comment: 「# locate php.ini」も試してみましたが、「/etc/php.ini」以外には、「/etc/php.ini.org」と「/etc/php.ini.rpmsave」があるだけで、他に関係ありそうな所は見つかりませんでした。

Comment: "11:58:17 nginx 2889 root ..." と表示されていますので、PID 2889 の nginx プロセスになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error_log` 関数を呼び出した結果が error.log に出力されるのであれば、(対象と思われる) PHP に対して grep 等で検索をかけて見るくらいしかなさそうです。

```bash
$ find /var/www/ -type f | xargs grep error_log
```